# When is wp_trim_excerpt() called?

Tags: functions, excerpt

There doesn't appear to be any reference to wp_trim_excerpt() outside of it's declaration - I've checked both the Trac and Xref - when does it work its magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already looked in XRef, you've seen this comment at the top of the doc block:

```
/**
  * Generates an excerpt from the content, if needed.
```

So it's not used in core, but is available for you to use if you need it.

### Update

Let me explain a little of what's going on:

> excerpt_length and excerpt_more are inside wp_trim_excerpt, and changing them does in fact change the_excerpt and get_the_excerpt. So wp_trim_excerpt has to be doing something somewhere.

Yes and no.  `excerpt_length` and `excerpt_more` are being generated by filters.  Here's the inside of the `wp_trim_excerpt()` function:

```
$excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
$excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
```

By default, `$excerpt_length` will be set to `55` and `$excerpt_more` will be set to `[...]`.  However, you can change this in themes and plugins.  Let's say I wanted to sent the length of trimmed excerpts to be 70 characters instead.  I'd use the following code:

```
function set_new_trim_length( $excerpt_length ) {
    return 70;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'set_new_trim_length' );
```

When I call `wp_trim_excerpt()` later, WordPress will pass that default value of `55` in to my filter function.  My filter function will then pass `70` back and `wp_trim_excerpt()` will use that instead.

`wp_trim_excerpt()` doesn't set or change `excerpt_length` or `excerpt_more` when you call it.  The function merely uses whatever filters you already have defined for those variables.

### Further Update

> But when you call the_excerpt or get_the_excerpt, they are modified by those filters, so what I want to know is 'when' they are modified by those filters.

This all depends on how you're building content.  There's a filter applied to `get_the_excerpt()` that will pass the generated content *through* the `wp_trim_excerpt()` function.

So if you hand-write an excerpt, the hand-written content will be passed through unchanged.

If you don't write an excerpt (`$post->post_excerpt = ''`), the content of the post is passed through `wp_trim_excerpt()` insted, shortened, and returned.

For reference, this filter is added on [line 147](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/default-filters.php.source.html#l147) of `/wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );
```

Comment: So if isn't not used then why does changing the filters inside of wp_trim_excerpt affect the the_excerpt and get_the_excerpt?

Comment: Expand on this by editing your question. Calling `wp_trim_excerpt()` doesn't affect `the_excerpt` or `get_the_excerpt()` at all. What do you think is being affected by what, exactly?

Comment: excerpt_length and excerpt_more are inside wp_trim_excerpt, and changing them does in fact change the_excerpt and get_the_excerpt. So wp_trim_excerpt has to be doing something somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that. But when you call the_excerpt or get_the_excerpt, they are modified by those filters, so what I want to know is 'when' they are modified by those filters. According to the Trac and Xref, wp_trim_excerpt - where those filters are used - isn't called or hooked anywhere by WP.

Comment: If you call `the_excerpt()`/`get_the_excerpt()` WordPress will return either the excerpt you've hand-written for the post or a shortened snippet of the post content (retrieved from `wp_trim_excerpt()`.  See my update for more ...

Comment: "add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );" that's what I was looking for. Thanks!